# Terraform - Multiple AWS codebuild projects require aws_codebuild_source_credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-codebuild

I have a lot of codebuild projects that are in use and they rely on `aws_codebuild_source_credential` to be created.

The problem for me is that some of the projects are specified in different folders and there is only one source credential for codebuild for an account.

This means that if I then delete a 'stack' which has created a `aws_codebuild_source_credential` in order to be able to create codebuild projects then the auth token is deleted for all codebuilds from that point on.

I cannot seem to find a data provider for the `aws_codebuild_source_credential` so I am looking for a way to reference one that is already created elsewhere.

When creating a codebuild project the oAuth token needs to be provided:

```
auth {
      type     = "OAUTH"
      resource = aws_codebuild_source_credential.github.arn
    }
```

The problem is how do I share a single `aws_codebuild_source_credential` so that I can pass this into separate code build projects, and should I run a destroy against any folder the token be left alone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comes down how you want to organise your terraform code, what I would do is

- move `aws_codebuild_source_credential` resource in a separate repository together with a `aws_ssm_parameter`  resource (potentially even create is as a module).
- Provision those resources first (pre seeding), when you provision the `aws_codebuild_source_credential` store it's `arn` in `aws_ssm_parameter` under a known name.
- Next time you provision a new codebuild project, retrieve the source credential arn from the SSM via the corresponding data resource [ssm_parameter](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter)

Comment: I did work out a way to do this, I almost did exactly what you suggest, I already have the github token in SSM, so I moved the github auth creation to a separate folder and I then use a string to create it, but I do like the idea of putting it in SSM.

I held off from posting my own answer until I was certain the stringify was actually going to work which took me a bit of time last night but essentially:

resource = "arn:aws:codebuild:${var.region}:${var.account_id}:token/github"

Comment: Also for anyone who might stumble across this in the future, this cli command is very useful for checking the source credentials availability on the fly:

aws codebuild list-source-credentials